# Не получается решить задачку

Tags: c++

Дан массив a[n,n]. Найти максимальный элемент массива среди элементов,
находящихся ниже главной диагонали. Элементы исходного массива
размещаются в текстовом файле Input.txt, результат записать в текстовый
файл Output.txt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include  <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    srand((int)time(0));
    int a[3][3];

    string path = "Input.txt";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);

    char ch;
    while (fin.get(ch)) {
        cout << ch;
    }

    int str = stoi(path);

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (a[i][j]>max) {
                max = a[i][j];
            }
            cout << max;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать **желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.

Comment: Так же исправь заголовок. "не получается решить задачку" не является описанием вообще ничего.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы обойти область под главной диагональю, достаточно изменить пределы циклов. Первый начать с единицы, а вот второй заканчивать j<i.
Кроме того, начальное значение max=0 не подойдёт, если все значения окажутся отрицательными.